# zipmap with multi-value keys

Tags: clojure, zipmap

The following:

```
(zipmap '(:a :b :c :c) '(1  2  3  4))
```

evals to: `{:c 4, :b 2, :a 1}`

I would like to get:

```
{:c '(3 4) :b '(2) :a '(1)}
```

instead.

How should I define my own `zipmap` that takes two lists and returns a map with multiple values for keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do

```
(defn zippy [l1 l2]
  (apply merge-with concat (map (fn [a b]{a (list b)}) l1 l2)))
        ;;; ⇒ #'user/zippy

(zippy '(:a :b :c :c) '(1  2  3  4))
        ;;; ⇒ {:c (3 4), :b (2), :a (1)}
```